# How can I display facebook page posts?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

All I want to do is display the 3 latest post from a facebook page on the companies website.
Here is my code currently using the access_token I can generate from facebooks graph api explorer.

```
<?php
$token = 'AAACfoqFEeZC0BAB9I7MpVUNXNQADQA8WCzBngUZAjCjZCDHZCi4kIDFDl3cQjLZCndgSyp9talZA4ERCfS14iMZAIQa2DuAEfHUYZAr0qlDYKwZDZD';
$feed = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/mypageidhere/posts?fields=message&limit=3&access_token='.$token);
$json = json_decode($feed);

foreach($json->data as $update) {

        echo $update->message.'<br /><hr />';   

}
?>
```

This works great except that access token expires. I don't want users to have to login to the site or anything like that. I've read through the Facebook API documentation but well, it's pretty terrible and wasn't helpful to me.  Is there a way to get a life long access token or not use an access_token at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution I found for this here it is. 
I used the facebook php/sdk

```
require_once "facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '<YOUR APP ID>',
  'secret' => '<YOUR SECRET>'
));

$query = 'SELECT post_id, message, permalink, likes, type, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = <PAGE ID> AND actor_id = <PAGE ID> LIMIT 3';
$facebook_data = $facebook->api(array(
                           'method' => 'fql.query',
                           'query' => $query,
                        ));
```

At first this returned an empty array and after a little trouble shooting I realized the page privacy settings needed to be tweaked to remove the age restriction. The page was then visible to everyone and this solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way to request offline access, but it seems like it has been deprecated. More information here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/